# How to assert generic is NonNullable

Tags: typescript

I have some methods that use `NonNullable<T>` to allow certain parts to assume that null checks have been performed before being called. I also have a function that will perform that check before then calling aforementioned methods.

My problem is that this function accepts a generic `T` which I need to narrow down to `NonNullable<T>`. When writing guarding code that checks for `null` and `undefined` values, this type is not automatically narrowed down to a non-nullable type by means of inference.

```js
export interface UrlParam<T> {
  defaultValue: T,
  encode: (value: NonNullable<T>) => string
  decode: (value: string) => NonNullable<T>
}

interface LatLng {
  lat: number
  lng: number
}

const COORDINATE_DELIMITER = ','

const locationParam: UrlParam<LatLng | null> = {
  defaultValue: null,
  encode: ({ lat, lng }) => [lat, lng].join(COORDINATE_DELIMITER),
  decode: value => {
    const [lat, lng] = value.split(COORDINATE_DELIMITER)

    return {
      lat: Number(lat),
      lng: Number(lng),
    }
  }
}

function encodeParam<T>(urlParam: UrlParam<T>, value: T) {
  return value !== undefined && value !== null ? urlParam.encode(value) : null
}
```

The `encodeParam` function produces the following compilation error:

> Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NonNullable'

I can resolve this by forcing the TypeScript compiler to treat `T` as `NonNullable<T>`:

```js
urlParam.encode(value as NonNullable<T>)
```

However I am looking for a solution where the compiler can actually infer this type based on the condition itself. Is this possible? Am I perhaps approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it might one day be possible to do this sort of thing with [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) and not a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) as in `value as NonNullable<T>` or the terser `value!` using the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator), for now the compiler will just not do this by itself.

---

Instead, if you want something the compiler can follow, my suggestion here would be to change `T` from meaning "the possibly-`null` or `undefined` type from which I need to remove `null` and `undefined`" to meaning "the non-`null` and non-`undefined` type to which I may need to add `null` and `undefined`.  You can use the [empty type `{}`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-oop.html#empty-types) to represent "anything except `null` and `undefined`" (yes, even primitives like `string` are assignable to `{}`), and [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T extends {}` so that no `undefined` or `null` types can sneak into your `T` type.

The refactoring would look like this:

```
export interface UrlParam<T extends {}> {
  defaultValue: T | null | undefined,
  encode: (value: T) => string
  decode: (value: string) => T
}
```

and then instead of `UrlParam<LatLng | null>` you could write `UrlParam<LatLng>`, and finally the following `encodeParam` will work as expected, because the compiler can use control flow analysis to filter a value of type `T | null | undefined` to just `T` by checking it:

```
function encodeParam<T extends {}>(urlParam: UrlParam<T>, value: T) {
  return value !== undefined && value !== null ? urlParam.encode(value) : null // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#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-WJIv8PI0gSkgA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have certainly considered using this approach, it however comes with a downside which makes it impossible to use for me.

I perhaps should have been more explicit in my question, but I need `defaultValue` to always be of type `T` since some will never be `null` or `undefined` (such as empty arrays or empty strings).

Comment: So then maybe something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbkMPW)?  You can always fall back to using an assertion, of course.

Comment: Yes, I think that a second generic would make the most sense for safety. I think in this case I will go for a type cast, to prevent leaking these details to other users of this interface for simplicity's sake.

That said, I was really hoping the compiler would be able to infer this type using control flow analysis . For example it could construct an `Exclude<T, null | undefined>` based on the conditions. But I am not a TS compiler engineer so what do I know 
